# Any way to get my .ROBLOSECURITY Cookie from Browser Dev Console?

Tags: javascript, roblox, developer-console

Is there any way to see my .ROBLOSECURITY in the dev console with any javascript code?

I've tried
`localStorage.getItem('.ROBLOSECURITY')` but, the Cookie is not storaged in the browsers  localStorage. Any help or any alternative methods?

Comment: LocalStorage and cookies are different. Have you tried getting the `. ROBLOSECURITY` cookie? Also, are you sure that is what the cookie is called?

Comment: I am sure that is what the cookie is called, and yes.

Comment: If it’s not an HttpOnly cookie, then `document.cookie`. If it is an HttpOnly cookie, it’s impossible with document-context JavaScript code unless the server exposes it some other way as well (which would be bad security).